# If a function $f$ is $L$-periodic and even, then $f'$ has $2$ zeros in $[0,L)$?

Tags: real-analysis, derivatives, periodic-functions

Let $f: \mathbb{R} \longrightarrow  \mathbb{R} $ be a differentiable and even function. If $f$ is periodic and the (minimal) period $L>0$, then $f'$ has $2$ zeros in $[0,L)$?

For example, this occurs if we consider $f(x)=\cos(x)$, for all $x \in  \mathbb{R} $, since in this case $L=2\pi$.

This is in general true?

Comment: I think you mean at least 2 zeros in $[0,L)$.

Comment: No, I meant **has two zeros**.Exactly as in the case $f (x)=\cos(x)$.

Comment: If the question is "does it have *exactly* two zeroes", the answer is no. A clear cut counterexample is ${y=c}$ for some constant ${c \in \mathbb{R}}$. It's differentiable, even and periodic for any period you like. But hence it's derivative is $0$ everywhere. And so will have an infinite number of zeroes on any interval, not just two

Comment: @Riemann'sPointyNose and in the case $f$ it is not constant?

Comment: @Riemann'sPointyNose Isn't the "(minimal) period" condition eliminating the constant function? The minimal period of $y=c$ is 0, right?

Comment: @curlycharcoal I thought that was defined as the fundemental period? So ${y=c}$ is still periodic, but does not have a fundemental period

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No. Define the function $f\colon[-2,2]\to\mathbb{R}$ by
\begin{align}
f(x)=\begin{cases}
-x^2+2\,, &\text{if $|x|\leq 1$}\,, \\
(|x|-2)^2\,, &\text{if $|x|>1$}\,.
\end{cases}
\end{align}
Then $f'(-2)=f'(2)=0$. We can shift $f$ by integral multiples of $T>4$. The resultant graph is a function $F$ as desired with period $T$, such that $F'(x)=0$ for all $x\in[4,T)$.

Edit: Forgot you were asking for the zeroes of $F'$ half way writing. $F'$ must have at least two zeroes, for there must be at least one local maximum and one local minimum in a period.